# Radio Buttons tied to a nullable enumeration returning null even if checked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

For a project I am working on, we have a setup where, in a view model, we have a property for a nullable three-way enumeration.  The problem I am having is that, there is a use case where all radio buttons are disabled, and even though a radio button is being programmatically checked, the view model is still receiving a null value for this enumeration value, and thus triggering the `Required` validation.

As far as the rules go, under normal circumstances, the reason the enum is allowed to be `null` is to require the user to make a choice between A, B, or C before being allowed to continue, as in the application I am working on, there are additional pieces of data that are needed later in the process.

**Question**: Why is it that, when the user clicks the submit button on the markup, that a null value is reaching the server, thus triggering the validation error?  As you can see in the script segment below, in this particular case, the radio button *is* being selected.

**Enumeration**

```
public enum ThreeWayEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool CanUseEnum
    {
        get
        {
            // Business logic goes here, but for this question it does not matter.
            // For this question the state causes the radio buttons to not be usable on the client.
            return false;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public ThreeWayEnum? MyEnum { get; set; }

    // Everything else is unimportant for this question.
}
```

**Controller** (Nothing special, I do not suspect the problem to be here at all.)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Save();
        return Redirect("SomeOtherAction", "ThisController");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**Markup**

```
@model MyViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "ThisController")
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CanUseEnum, new { id = "can-use-enums" })

    <div class="horz-group">
       <div class="span9">Select some option</div>
       <div class="span7">
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyEnum, ThreeWayEnum.A, new { id = "opt-A" } )
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyEnum, ThreeWayEnum.B, new { id = "opt-B" } )
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyEnum, ThreeWayEnum.C, new { id = "opt-C" } )
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horz-group">
        <button type="submit">Continue</button>
    </div>
}
```

**Script**

```
var $canUseEnum = $('#can-use-enums'),
    $optA = $('#opt-A'),
    $optB = $('#opt-B'),
    $optC = $('#opt-C');

$(document).ready(function () {
    disableSelectionIfIneligible();
});

function disableSelectionIfIneligible() {
    if($canUseEnum.val() == 'True')
        return;

    $optA.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $optB.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $optC.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    // Selects the 'default' option.
    $optA.attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a sanity check, I commented out the lines that disable the radio buttons, and tried again.  Sure enough, disabling the radio buttons *is* preventing a value from being conveyed to the server.

If you disable all of the radio buttons for an option, they will return `null` as their value.